# Serilog Context set up late in a pipeline is not available early on return pipe

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog, .net-core-3.1

Using Serilog with `.Enrich.FromLogContext()`
I am adding Logged In User as a scope late in pipeline `using LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", user.Name)`

The issue is that this scope is not available on return pipeline like in ExceptionHandling, RequestLogging etc.. So I am missing important information when exception occurred.

Example of pipeline ::

```
RequestLogging --> ExceptionHandling --> Authentication --> Controller |
                                                                       |
RequestLogging <-- ExceptionHandling <-- Authentication --> Controller |
```

I tried with `IDiagnosticContext` but it is only available in `UseSerilogRequestLogging()`

Could you please advice how to work around it?

Comment: I assume you have seen [Nick's guide](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/); I have not personally tried so cant actually help, but perhaps a comment there might be the best place to ask?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Invoke` method of the exception handling middleware you have as argument the current `HttpContext`. Knowing this you can access the identity property of the context.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
  try
  {
    await this.next(context);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    var username = context.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "__unknown";
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("Username", username))
    {
     this.logger.Log(......)
    }
  }
}
```

This way you will have access to the logged user even if the exception middleware is first in the pipeline as long as the exception has occurred after the authentication middleware.

---

**EDIT 02/10/2020**

If you need the identity information in the `.UseSerilogRequestLogging()` you can use the overload witch accepts options. Check the last example in [Request logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#request-logging) on their github page.

Comment: No this will only make it available in the catch block but not the further pipeline anymore

Comment: @user1316502 Well this will push the property for the exception handling middleware. If you need it it also in the RequestLogging check my edit